# Device to smooth out power consumption of a heat gun

Tags: power, mains

When I turn on a 2KW hot air gun that is not set to full power it does on-off power control which makes bulbs in my home flicker which I understand that it happens because of small voltage dips because of the additional 10 amps of current.

There's probably no harm in this flicker but I'm just wondering if it is feasible to make a device to plug in between the hot air gun and the mains that would consume a more even current at the mains side so that the lights don't flicker.

Comment: "Inrush limiter"

Comment: Have you tried an extension cord running to as close as you can to the point where power enters your home and is split for the different circuits with the different outlets? Basically, the power grid (with all its power plants attached) should have close-to-zero source resistance, meaning that give or take 10 A won't make anything flicker at the level of what's distributed near and far. Things with higher impedance happen once the distribution voltage is transformed to the 220V the consumer gets – and thus, the closer you get to that transformer, the lower the effects of current draw changes .

Comment: In my understanding an inrush limiter is to avoid high inrush currents which is not the case with the hot air gun which is a purely resistive load and is probably turned on/off at zero voltage points. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is natural long wire resistance to drop 5% of voltage or 10% of power in old house wiring . Heavier (-3AWG) or 1/2 the length to breaker panel will cut these losses by 50%. You can

Comment: - get a Triac dimmer instead

Comment: The problem is not with the heat gun, but with the wiring in your house.

Answer (score 1):

If you control power to the heat gun via its power lead then your voltage reduction circuit will affect the fan speed.

[image]

*Figure 1. Voltage reduction by triac phase-angle control.*

To do what you want you would have to hack the heat gun and add a heavy duty light dimmer to the heat coil only. This will do phase-angle control via a triac and switch the heater voltage on part way through each mains half-cycle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhG3RZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Modification schematic.*

Comment: What the difference between what the heat gun already does internally and this? won't it still consume current in pulses and cause the same flickering? higher switching frequency?

Comment: Yes, but at 100 or 120 Hz (twice mains frequency) it won't be noticeable to the eye. Your question doesn't give the frequency of flicker so we don't know if this is once every few seconds or twice per second or faster.

Comment: it's about 10Hz I think.